# How to send data immediately in epoll ET mode when connect established

Tags: epoll

My server needs to send data when client connects to it. I am using Epoll ET mode.
But how to do it? Could any one give me a simple example for me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are listening on your socket (`socket`, `bind`, `listen`), and have added it's descriptor to epoll (`epoll_create` and `epoll_ctl`), then `epoll_wait` will tell you when there is a new connection to accept.

First you accept the connection (`sockfd` is descriptor of socket you're listening on, `efd` is epoll instance) and add it to your epoll instance:

```
int connfd = accept4(sockfd, NULL, 0, SOCK_NONBLOCK);

struct epoll_event ev;
ev.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET;
ev.data.fd = connfd;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &ev)
```

Then you go back to your main loop and call `epoll_wait` again. It will tell you when the socket is ready for writing, and you just happily `write` or `sendfile` away.

Add lots of error checking, and probably `TCP_CORK` and you're done. There's a working example on [github.com/grahamking/netshare/](https://github.com/grahamking/netshare/blob/master/share.c).

I hope this gives you enough information to get started.